# How to fix html table col width after hiding other cols?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html table having 5 columns. In the design time, I use  to specify each column's width with relative width %. In the runtime, the javascript codes hide three columns, the other two columns become very wide. How can I let the remaining two columns' width not changed? But I don't want to use the pix to fix the width.

Thank you.

Comment: try with visibility:hidden; with javascript It will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way is using float : left.

```
td {
    float:left;
}

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text hidden</td>
    <td>Some text hidden</td>
    <td>Some text visibile</td>
    <td>Some text hidden</td>
    <td>Some text visibile</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try by giving maximum width of 20% to every TD or TH in css.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the way those columns are hidden: If they are being set to `display:none;` (either with an inline style set by js, or by adding/removing a class) then you can change that to `visibility:hidden;` - this way they will still take up space, but will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you use viewport width `vw` instead of percent `%` it will work.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 20vw;
}


td:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text hidden</td>
    <td>Some text hidden</td>
    <td>Some text visibile</td>
    <td>Some text hidden</td>
    <td>Some text visibile</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```